# Figuring out userId from Twitter's Streaming Response Status

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

Per Twitter documentation A follow is:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters

```
A comma-separated list of user IDs, indicating the users whose Tweets 
should be delivered on the stream. Following protected users is not 
supported. For each user specified, the stream will contain:

1. Tweets created by the user.
2. Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
3. Replies to any Tweet created by the user.
4. Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
5. Manual replies, created without pressing a reply button (e.g. 
   “@twitterapi I agree”).
 ....
```

......

1 and 2 are straight forward , to get them from Status JSON just do 
status.getUser().getId()
for 3 , status.inReplyToUserId

for 4 , status.getRetweetedStatus().getUser().getId()

but how the heck do you get the last one ?   Do those become mentions ?